# i am trying to load a json file not able to load it

Tags: json, pandas

I am trying to load a JSON file in pandas but not able to load it throwing some error [screen shot of the eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozCFH.png) so the error showing up is value error: expected object or value 
    business = pd.read_json('yelp_dataset.json', lines=True)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the [orient](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

Try this

```
business = pd.read_json('yelp_dataset.json', lines=True , orient='records')
```